# Xcode C Programming - Order of Output is Wrong

Tags: c, xcode, output, mutex

I try to program about semaphores and the problem is, output of the Xcode is not in true order. I think it is because of 'printf()' functions buffer. I am giving the code, and the result of it in Xcode. There are some code parts like 'for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)' to robust the mutual exclusions and data corruption. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 3
int ctr = 0;

sem_t sem;

void *IncCounter();

int main(void) {

    int ret_value;
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);

    for(int t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
        ret_value=pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, IncCounter, NULL);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *IncCounter(){
    for (int l=0; l<5; l++) {
        sem_wait(&sem);
        ++ctr;
        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {

            }
        printf("Counter is: %d\n", ctr);
        sem_post(&sem);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}
```

I am now giving the output that I take from Xcode.

```
Counter is: 3
Counter is: 3
Counter is: 3
Counter is: 6
Counter is: 7
Counter is: 8
Counter is: 9
Counter is: 10
Counter is: 10
Counter is: 12
Counter is: 13
Counter is: 14
Counter is: 14
Counter is: 14
Counter is: 15
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

How can I avoid from this? Thanks a lot for reading,

Mert

Comment: The thread function's signature is wrong, should be `void* foo(void*)`. That "delay" for loop is most likely being eliminated by the compiler, use a `sleep`-type function to get a delay. Are you compiling (and linking) with `-pthread`?

Comment: Please explain what order you expected, and why.

Comment: Note your *main()* thread should be waiting for its child threads to run to end.

Comment: 1) I changed the signature but it is same. Also with 'for loop' I try to keep thread busy to see some possible interruptions. But when I write 'sleep' instead of 'for' to keep system busy, it will be a 'suspended thread'.

Comment: 2) Order should be 'Counter is:1' to 'Counter is:15' without any repetition.

Comment: 3) Actually it waits; please look at 'pthread_exit(NULL);' code line in main function.